# How to display php form errors ONLY beside the field?

Tags: html, forms, php

I'm building a simple PHP contact form, and my error messages DO show up beside each form field the way I'd like, but they are also appearing at the top of the form where I've written the includes PHP code on my HTML file. I want to get rid of the errors displaying at the top where the includes code is. This is the includes code:

```
<?php include("includes/form.inc.php"); ?>
```

This is the html form code I have:

```
<?php echo $finalMsg; ?>

        <form method="post" action="contact.php">

            <fieldset>

                <ul>

                    <li class="instructions">(*) Required Fields</li>

                    <li>
                        <p><?php echo $errors["firstname"]; ?></p>
                        <label for="firstname" class="lined_up"><span class="asterisk">*</span> First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="firstname" 
                                id="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST["firstname"]; ?>" />
                                                      <!-- This keeps the content you enter in this field in place if you miss a field & have to resubmit-->
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <p><?php echo $errors["lastname"]; ?></p>
                        <label for="lastname" class="lined_up"><span class="asterisk">*</span> Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="lastname" 
                            id="lastname" value="<?php echo $_POST["lastname"]; ?>" />
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <p><?php echo $errors["email"]; ?></p>
                        <label for="email" class="lined_up"><span class="asterisk">*</span> Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Please type a valid email." name="email" 
                            id="email" value="<?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p><?php echo $errors["message"]; ?></p> 
                        <label for="message" class="message lined_up"><span class="asterisk">*</span> Message:</label>
                        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Please enter your message here."><?php echo isset($_POST['message'])? $_POST['message'] : ''; ?></textarea>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
```

This is the PHP code I have:

```
<?php 

// 
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

    //This is checking if the string length in the firstname field was greater than 1 character
    if(strlen($_POST["firstname"]) > 1)
    {

        $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
        //echo $firstname;
    }

    else
    {
        //echo "You did not type in first name";
        $errors["firstname"] = "<span class=\"error\">You did not type in a first name.</span>";
    }


    if(strlen($_POST["lastname"]) > 1)
    {

        $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    }

    else
    {
        $errors["lastname"] = "<span class=\"error\">You did not type in a last name.</span>";
    }


    if(strlen($_POST["email"]) > 1)
    {

        $email = $_POST["email"];

        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email = $email;
        }

        else {
            $errors["email"] = "<span class=\"error\">Email is invalid.</span>";
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $errors["email"] = "<span class=\"error\">You did not type in an email address.</span>";
    }

    //This is checking if the string length in the message field was greater than 1 character
    if(strlen($_POST["message"]) > 1)
    {

        $message = $_POST["message"];
        //echo $firstname;
    }

    else
    {

        $errors["message"] = "<span class=\"error\">You did not type in a message.</span>";
    }


    // Code to tell form NOT to send form if there are any errors.
    if($errors < 1)
    {
            $to = "liz@lizshannon.com";
            $from = $email;
            // headers makes sure you have a reply-to address
            $headers = "From: {$from}" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

            $subject =  
                "From: ($from)" . "<br />" .
                "First name: ($firstname)" . "<br />" .
                "Last name: ($lastname)" . "<br />" .
                "Email: ($email)" . "<br />" .
                "Message: ($message)";

            if(mail($to, $from, $subject, $headers))
            {
                $finalMsg = "<p class=\"success\">Thank you! Your email was sent.</p>";
            }

            else {
                $finalMsg = "<p class=\"error\">Your email was NOT sent. Please try again.</p>";
            }

}

?>

<?php

//each error is displayed

foreach($errors as $value) {

echo "<span>$value</span><br />";

}
    }
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do a client side check with jquery validator plugins

Comment: it's hard to tell from your question but I'm assuming they show up as PHP errors. Add `display_errors(false);` at the top of your code. Better yet turn them off in php.ini if you have access to the php configuration on your server. It should always be off on production sites

Answer (score 1):

remove echo from or you can remove whole block of for loop because you dont want to print it now

```
foreach($errors as $value) {

echo "<span>$value</span><br />";

}
```

and you should use jquery or javascript validation at client side which so that time will be reduced for server-client communication

Comment: You should never exclusively rely on client side validation. This would open up a huge security hole.

Comment: @LoganBailey yeah but you should check client side as well as serverside for more security. i told to add client side not to remove server side.

Comment: @yadav chetan: what's benefit of both side validation? , is there any possibility to have different result in client and server validation?

Comment: benefits of clients side validation is that you dont need to communicate every time with server. it checks by your browser only so it tends to fast execution of your code. but you must place server side too because in case javascript disabled true in browser then browser dont check the client side validation

Answer (score 1):

just remove this block of code:

```
<?php
  //each error is displayed
   foreach($errors as $value) {
    echo "<span>$value</span><br />";
    }
}
```